# Determining length of array of strings ignoring commas/periods (letters only)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, string

I'm trying to find the best way to determine the letter count in an array of strings. I'm splitting the string, and then looping every word, then splitting letters and looping those letters.

When I get to the point where I determine the length, the problem I have is that it's counting commas and periods too. Thus, the length in terms of letters only is inaccurate.

I know this may be a lot shorter with regex, but I'm not well versed on that yet. My code is passing most tests, but I'm stuck where it counts commas.

```
E.g. 'You,' should be string.length = "3"
```

Sample code:

```
def abbr(str)
  new_words = []
  str.split.each do |word|
    new_word = []
    word.split("-").each do |w| # it has to be able to handle hyphenated words as well
      letters = w.split('')
       if letters.length >= 4
         first_letter = letters.shift
         last_letter = letters.pop
         new_word << "#{first_letter}#{letters.count}#{last_letter}"
       else 
         new_word << w
      end
    end
   new_words << new_word.join('-')
 end
 new_words.join(' ')
```

I tried doing `gsub` before looping the words, but that wouldn't work because I don't want to completely remove the commas. I just don't need them to be counted.

Any enlightenment is appreciated.

Comment: I'm having a hard time determining the purpose of the `abbr` method. Can you please prove a sample input to the method and then what you'd like to have returned? If you just want a quick way to count letter characters in a String: `str.scan(/[[:alpha:]]/).length`

Comment: Sorry @LucasNelson - the goal is to abbreviate a word if its length is 4 or more. E.g. `internationalization = i18n`.  So we get the first and last letter, then count the letters in between. I updated the code, I can't do scan because it's an array (not an expert, so I'm probably missing something)

Comment: @LizGee, could you please provide more examples? I don't quite understand what you need to do too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr = ["Now is the time for y'all Rubiests",
       "to come to the aid of your bowling team."]
arr.join.size
  #=> 74
```

**Without a regex**

```
def abbr(arr)
  str = arr.join
  str.size - str.delete([*('a'..'z')].join + [*('A'..'Z')].join).size
end

abbr arr
  #=> 58
```

Here and below, `arr.join` converts the array to a single string.

**With a regex**

```
R = /
    [^a-z] # match a character that is not a lower-case letter
    /ix    # case-insenstive (i) and free-spacing regex definition (x) modes

def abbr(arr)
  arr.join.gsub(R,'').size
end

abbr arr
  #=> 58
```

You could of course write:

```
arr.join.gsub(/[^a-z]/i,'').size
  #=> 58
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def abbr(str)
  str.gsub /\b\w+\b/ do |word|
    if word.length >= 4
      "#{word[0]}#{word.length - 2}#{word[-1]}"
    else
      word
    end
  end
end
```

The regex in the `gsub` call says "one or more word characters preceded and followed by a word boundary". The block passed to gsub operates on each word, the return from the block is the replacement for the 'word' match in gsub.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for each character that whether its ascii value lies in 97-122 or 65-90.When this condition is fulfilled increment a local variable that will give you total length of string without any number or any special character or any white space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that (short version):

```
a.map { |x| x.chars.reject { |char| [' ', ',', '.'].include? char } }
```

Long version with explanation:

```
a = ['a, ', 'bbb', 'c c, .']     # Initial array of strings
excluded_chars = [' ', ',', '.'] # Chars you don't want to be counted

a.map do |str|                   # Iterate through all strings in array
  str.chars.reject do |char|     # Split each string to the array of chars
    excluded_chars.include? char # and reject excluded_chars from it 
  end.size # This returns [["a"], ["b", "b", "b"], ["c", "c"]] 
end        # so, we take #size of each array to get size of the string

# Result: [1, 3, 2]
```